# Save an Attachment in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.net application and on page #2 (pg2) the user can upload an attachment.  On page #3 (pg3) is my confirmation where the user clicks a submit button. This then sends an email to me with all the details in it. This functionality works fine but I don't get the attachment as I don't know how to pass it page to page in the session.

**Page 2 Code**

The code below show how I pass details entered on page 2 in the session

```
protected void pg2button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["pg2"] = txtData2.Text;
    Session["pg2Yes"] = pg2Yes.Checked ? "Yes" : "";
// CODE HERE TO PASS/STORE UPLOADED DOC
    Session["pg2No"] = pg2No.Checked ? "No" : "";
    Response.Redirect("/Quotation/pg3.aspx");
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">         
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Upload"></asp:Label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachment" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:FileUpload>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Page 3 Code**

```
protected void pg3button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        //Create the msg object to be sent
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        //Add your email address to the recipients
        msg.To.Add("test@hotmail.co.uk");

        //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress("test@hotmail.co.uk");
        msg.From = address;

        //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
        msg.Subject = "Quote Requst";

        msg.Body = Label1.Text + " " + Session["pg1input"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label5.Text + " " + Session["emailinput"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label2.Text + " " + Session["pg1dd"].ToString()
                    +Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label3.Text + " " + Session["pg2"].ToString();

        //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it

        //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@hotmail.co.uk", "Password");
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        //Send the msg
        client.Send(msg);

        Response.Redirect("/Quotation/pg4.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        lblResult.Text = "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "There was a problem sending your request. Please try again." + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "If the error persists, please contact us." + "</div>" + "</div>";
    }
}
```

The link below I can get to work but only if the upload field is on the same page
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: What kind of control did you use for the upload? Can you get the bytes somehow?

Comment: don't save attachment, save path rather in Session

Comment: @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin Not to sure how to do this

Comment: @DanielV when editing questions, please also remove tags ("ASP.NET", "C#") from titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get file content and store in session (add to pg2 click event before redirect):

```
var file = fuAttachment.PostedFile;
if (file != null)
{
    var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
    Session["FileContent"] = content;
    Session["FileContentType"] = file.ContentType;
}
```

For download this file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", ((byte[])Session["FileContent"]).Length);
Response.ContentType = (string)Session["FileContentType"];
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName");
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])Session["FileContent"]);

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

At pg3 For attach stored file:

```
var contentStream = new MemoryStream((byte[]) Session["FileContent"]);
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(contentStream,"file.ext",(string) Session["FileContentType"])); // Or store file name to Session for get it here.
```

Comment: May seem a little dumb, but am I right in saying this should go in my `protected void pg2button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: I have tried your code and it doesn't work as once I click my 'Next' button it redirects me to my first page again. Could you please help me out or provide the code for me.  I tried adding the code under your 'Store In Session'.  Also I have added my email code from pg3, if possible could you please help me out with this also as i'm a little confused with it all. Thanks

Comment: @murday1983 I will create a project for store file and send mail with this attachment. I will return to you. (I wrote it by notepad :D)

Comment: @murday1983 See my edited answer. I am added mail attachment.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where about's do I need to the put the 'Download' section or do I not need this bit as I am storing in my session

Comment: Worked great.  Just made a couple of tweaks added the following line to the 'Session' `Session["File"] = fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName;` so that it returned my file name & extension so that the attachment can be opened directly from the email.  Also updated the `msg.Attachments.Add` code to use my new file name/extension session name so it now looks like `msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(contentStream, (string)Session["File"], (string)Session["FileContentType"]));` again so that the attachment attaches the email with the file name & extension

Comment: Could you please have a look at my new post regarding attachements as I have now custom styled my `FileUpload` field and it no longer works as it doesn't recognise my ID in my code behind no matter where I put the ID. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964475/email-attachment-no-longer-working-as-custom-styled-aspfileupload-field

Answer (score 0):

If you store the path in the session, then you can get the bytes for the file with this method:

```
private byte[] GetFileBytes(string myPath)
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(myPath);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    using (FileStream fs = file.OpenRead())
    {
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```